# Prove NP-completeness of CLIQUE-OR-INDEPENDENT-SET

Tags: reduction, np-complete, np, clique-problem, independent-set

First of all, I want to mention that this is my **homework**. However, to solve my problem I can use any literature I want.

Even though I think that problem is clear from its name, I will give it description: *"For given undirected graph G and given integer k, does G contain totally connected (clique) subgraph of size k or totally disconnected subgraph (independent set) of size k."*

I know about polynomial reductions from `3-SAT` to `CLIQUE` and from `3-SAT` to `INDEPENDENT-SET`. (http://mlnotes.com/2013/04/29/npc.html) However, I have problem with this one because I cannot combine those two reductions. I also tried reduction from `CLIQUE` to `CLIQUE-OR-INDEPENDENT-SET` but without much success.

So I would really appreciate any hints!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out reduction from problem `INDEPENDENT-SET` to `CLIQUE-OR-INDEPENDENT-SET`. All you need to do is to add `n` isolated vertices to graph `G` (which is an instance of `INDEPENDENT-SET` and has `n` vertices). Let call this newly created graph `G'` (instance of `CLIQUE-OR-INDEPENDENT-SET`). Then it is not hard to prove that `G` has `k` independent-set iff `G'` has `n+k` independent-set of clique (since, by construction, it cannot have `n+k`clique).